# SQLITE Transactions : get total count

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using transactions to insert record to my database. Can you please tell me whether this is the right way to get total inserted record (return by numrow)? Also, in the code below, if some insert fails, will it continue to next insertion or will exit (I didn't use endTransaction in Catch block)?

```
int numrow = 0;
try{
            db.beginTransaction();
            for(mylibman cn : insertlist){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_LIBID, cn.getLibid());
                values.put(KEY_NAME, cn.getBookname());
                db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                numrow++;
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return numrow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will also count records that were ignored.

`insertWithOnConflict` returns the rowid of the inserted record, or -1, so you have to check for that:

```java
if (db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE) != -1)
    numrow++;
```

The `insertWithOnConflict` function does not throw an exception if a record is not inserted due to a conflict. However, it *will* throw if there is some other error, such as an unknown column name, or a read-only database.

You should not blindly ignore exceptions; just use `try`/`finally`:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (...) {
        ...
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should check like this

```
    int numrow = 0;
    try{
                db.beginTransaction();
                for(mylibman cn : insertlist){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(KEY_LIBID, cn.getLibid());
                    values.put(KEY_NAME, cn.getBookname());
                    //do like this
                    long insertedId=db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                    if(insertedId!=-1)
                    {
                          numrow++;

                    }

                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
            return numrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the answers here reflect the documentation:
*"returns:
the row ID of the newly inserted row **OR the primary key of the existing row** if the input param 'conflictAlgorithm' = CONFLICT_IGNORE OR -1 if any error"*

Since the author  wants to know the 'inserted' columns, both answers are wrong. The number inserted rows could be 0, as they already exist. However "CONFLICT_IGNORE" will make insert return the existing primary key, so the numrow will be the rows you 'tried' to insert and didn't fail, but not the rows 'inserted'.

You might have to use the flag "SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ABORT" or "SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL" depending on what and how you insert.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29